# Python Equation of the plane defined by principal components on Dimensionality Reduction

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca, plane

I need to understand the plane´s equation written in python code.

From a 3d dataset it applies dimensionality reduction to get the first two main components.

pca.components_ are these two vectors that define a plane

array([[-0.93636116, -0.29854881, -0.18465208],
       [ 0.34027485, -0.90119108, -0.2684542 ]])

I would like to understand the last two lines, where the plane is defined:

I have been taking a look at all kind of plane equations, but could not find any similar to z = (R[0, 2] * x1 + R[1, 2] * x2) / (1 - R[2, 2])

```
axes = [-1.8, 1.8, -1.3, 1.3, -1.0, 1.0]

x1s = np.linspace(axes[0], axes[1], 10)
x2s = np.linspace(axes[2], axes[3], 10)
x1, x2 = np.meshgrid(x1s, x2s)

C = pca.components_
R = C.T.dot(C)
z = (R[0, 2] * x1 + R[1, 2] * x2) / (1 - R[2, 2])
```

What describes R?
I know it is a 3x3 Matrix and it´s ussed its last column on the next line,
but Why?

Here is the plot:
[image: Plot with the plane]

Thanks in advance for helping to understand it.

Same plane can be plotted like this with the basic plane equation:
a*x + b*y + c*z = 0 with(a,b,c) as the normal vector.

```
normal = np.cross(C[0,:],C[1,:])
z_dav = (-normal[0]*x1-normal[1]*x2)/(normal[2])

ax.plot_surface(x1, x2, z, alpha=0.1, color="y")
ax.plot_surface(x1, x2, z_dav, alpha=0.3, color="g")
```

[both planes are the same: z(yellow) and z_dav(green)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8asL.jpg)

Anyway I still want to understand this:

```
R = C.T.dot(C)
z = (R[0, 2] * x1 + R[1, 2] * x2) / (1 - R[2, 2])
```